# Is there an easy way to distribute the Access Database Engine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm using an Access Database (accdb) with my VB 2010 Application

I know I need to install the Access Database Engine on each workstation that needs to run my program.

However, I can see a logistical nightmare if I have to manually install the Access Database Engine on 100+ workstations manually.

I know a MSI doesn't exist. I'm looking for a solution to automate the installation of the Database Engine when the software installs.

Has anyone else overcome this problem.

Comment: Through what methods are you planning to or currently deploying to each workstation? Obviously a Windows Installer allows you to script custom actions for installing drivers along-with an application, but it's not clear if that would fit in with your deployment strategy.

Comment: I developed an software using entirely on MS Access, used Advance Installer, to check if the user PC has Access installed, if not the installer would install MS Access runtime

Comment: Does your application use any database features that are specific to the .accdb file format (e.g., event-driven data macros, Attachment fields, etc.)?

Comment: No, the accdb database is just used to store tables and data

Comment: Answering JonathonOgden's comment, I use the Visual Studio Installer tool, I've add the accessdatabaseengine.exe as a custom action (install), used the /quiet and /passive switches. During the installation, setup fails at the point the access engine is installing, claiming it can't install because another process is running, which I assume is the parent installation.

Comment: With inno setup you can detect if you need to install it and offer to download and run the setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application does not use any database features specific to the .accdb file format then you could greatly simplify matters by using an .mdb file to store your data. You could target your VB.NET project to the x86 (32-bit) environment and have it use the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider that is included with every Windows install. That way you could just distribute your app without having to worry about installing ACE.

Comment: Thanks Gord, using mdb works fine (just tested on a clean Windows 7 install) so it's fair to say that mdb is still acceptable to use over accdb for table/data functionality